# What is difference between requires public VS requires transitive in Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

I have learn that in order to use any other exported module, we need to specify that module as a `requires`:

```
module mymodule{
       requires othermodule.xyz;
}
```

When `othermodule` uses on `thirdmodule`  and `mymodule` needs that as well,  `othermodule` should define transitive dependency like this:

```
module othermodule {
       requires transitive thirdmodule  
}
```

However, I have seen many sites that use the `public` keyword for this situation:

```
module othermodule {
       requires public  thirdmodule  
}
```

What is the difference there is between the two forms; i.e. `requires public` and `requires transitive`?

Comment: Did you mean `requires static`? There is no such thing as `requires public`

Comment: I have edited the question to remove the subquestions that are duplicate.

Comment: @StephenC I am not sure what the consensus on Meta for such edits would be which could change the meaning altogether. I would still vote to close this question as no/research or no debugging attempts though.

Comment: @nullpointer - If you want to know what the consensus is, ask on meta.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `requires public` was part of an earlier version of the modules sub-language that was revised before the release of Java 9.  According to the Java 9 JLS, the `public` keyword is not allowed in a *ModuleDirective*: see [JLS 7.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.7).

The sites that use the `requires public` syntax are out of date / incorrect.  This is acknowledged in the following, for example:

- [The State of the Module system](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/) by Mark Reinhold (version dated 2016/3/8)

Basically `requires public` is outdated (now invalid) syntax, and `requires transitive` is its replacement.